# How to combine two dictionaries that have dictionaries as values (second-level dictionaries)

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, keyvaluepair

I currently have two dictionary's. I would like to take the second dictionary which contains more key-value pairs and append the dictionary values to the values in the first dictionary.

```
Dictionary1 = {'47289': {'totcount': 5.0, 'totunits': 89.8}, 
               '18109': {'totcount': 82.92, 'totunits': 829.67}}

Dictionary2 = {'47289': {'average': 927.90, 'median': 288.8}, 
               '18109': {'average': 927.92, 'median': 3728.97},
               '92738': {'average': 729.91, 'median': 472.88}}

Result = {'47289': {'totcount': 5.0, 'totunits': 89.8, 'average': 927.90, 'median': 288.8}, 
          '18109': {'totcount': 82.92, 'totunits': 829.67, 'average': 927.92, 'median': 3728.97}}
```

When I try using the python `update()` function:

```
Dictionary1.update(Dictionary2)
```

The result is the first dictionary with the second dictionary values and the first dictionary values have been deleted.

```
Dictionary1 = {'47289': {'average': 927.90, 'median': 288.8}, 
               '18109': {'average': 927.92, 'median': 3728.97}}
```

Comment: Not exactly. The OP wants to merge second-level dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for key, value in Dictionary1.iteritems():
    value.update(Dictionary2[key])
```

(It is the nested dictionaries that you need to update.)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!